# How to understand that file was uploaded with Selenium and Ruby?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am writing my first automatization script with Selenium + Ruby and I need to upload a file to the web application.
The thing is that uploading takes some time (from 30sec to 3min, it depends). After the file was uploaded, I need to click "Save" button.

How could my code recognize that the uploading process was completed and it can continue to execute?

Here is the standard code, just for your reference:

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
driver.navigate.to 'my-website.com/upload'

driver.find_element(id: 'upload-input').send_keys('my/path/to/the/document')
driver.find_element(id: 'upload-button').click

**Now my code needs to wait till upload will be completed and then to click "Save" button**

driver.find_element(id: 'save-button').click
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From Selenium's perspective, there isn't anything from the file upload that you can use, but there is hopefully something else on the website you can use.

Does anything on the site change once a file has completed uploading? Maybe an icon that appears, or a box that says "upload complete"?

If so, you can use a conditional wait for that element to appear!

Something like:

```rb
Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(timeout: 30).until {
  driver.find_element(id: 'upload-complete').displayed?
}
```

You'll want to wrap that in a `rescue` block down the line to catch for edge-cases like the element not existing, but hopefully that gets you started!

Comment: He wants wait for file to be uploaded not to wait for the file field. Selenium automatically waits until file gets uploaded to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't over use Capybara/Selenium, even if they are cool and can add some value to your project, they are the more brittle, capricious and slower part of any TDD suite and it never should be more than 10% of all your tests. Using it for testing the upload of a file is clearly an anti-pattern.

Use a request rspec and a javascript TDD lib (Jest/Enzyme) to test the new functionality instead. The current tread to test everything with Capybara/Selenium is insane.